# Laptop crashes with a flickering screen

Tags: crash, troubleshooting, thinkpad

My Thinkpad (W530 with Optimus graphics) sometimes suddenly crashes with a flickring screen. It doesn't react anymore and it is also not accessible via ssh anymore.

This doesn't happen if the laptop is on the docking station. I use usually use it 4 to 6 hours without dock a day sometimes with battery or sometimes with 135W power adapter and it crashes 1 to 2 times a day.

What are the steps I should to to find the source of the problem?

Here is a video of my screen after a crash: http://videobin.org/+ezg/itz.html (the color is actually more gray).

Im am using ubuntu xenial. The laptop has a samsung ssd.

I had two ideas what it might be, the first was that it might be an ssd problem, but then the crash should also happen on the docking station. The second was that it might be a problem with the battery or the power adapter. But I couldn't reproduce the crash and don't know how to narrow it down.

Comment: I am afraid I wont accept Java Applets from unknown sources for security reasons.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not have any demonstrable connection to being a U&L question; it sounds more like a hardware problem.

Comment: The connection is that I use linux and I want to know how to debug this problem from my linux platform and the syslogs.

Comment: Can you replicate this condition if you boot the laptop off a live CD/USB image?  If not then it might be OS, if yes then its hardware, and you need to start an iterative break-fix testing regime.   Or, if its under warranty start that process.